# JSF - Selectonemenu array int

Tags: jsf

i want to set value in array but receive Classcastexception..

example of code:
page.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Really simple CRUD</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:growl autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true"/>
        <h:selectOneMenu converter="javax.faces.Integer" value="#{adminMBean.a[0]}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:commandButton value="ok" action="#{adminMBean.ok()}"/>
        <h:outputText value="sa:#{adminMBean.a[0]}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

```
@ManagedBean(name = "adminMBean")
@RequestScoped
public class AdminMBean {
  int[] a=new int[1];
public AdminMBean(){}
    public int[] getA() {
    return a;
}
public void setA(int[] a) {
    this.a = a;
}
}
```

how to set value into array with selectonemenu?

Comment: why do you want to set the selected value in an array? there will always be a single selected item. then why not use just an `int`?

Comment: In the future questions, it'd be helpful if you post the entire exception instead of ignoring/overgeneralizing it as irrelevant information. It is namely *not* irrelevant information. Exceptions are namely usually already the whole answer at its own. We just have to translate them in layman's terms for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you *read* the `ClassCastException` message? It should be something like this:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: Unable to add an object of type [java.lang.Integer] to an array of objects of type [int]

See, you should be using `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`.

```
private Integer[] a = new Integer[1];

public Integer[] getA() {
    return a;
}
```

The setter is by the way unnecessary. It wouldn't be used in this construct.